# iterate through dir of dirs/subdirs printing only subdirs name

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a base dir with the following structure:

```
name_a/foo/...
name_b/bar/...
name_c/baz/...
```

This base dir has many subfolders with names_X, and inside each of those, there is a single dir that contains also other files.

I´m trying to get a list with only the subdirs names, i.e., my goal is to print:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

, but I´m printing also the parents:

```
name_a
name_b
name_c
foo
bar
baz
```

I´m using this:

```
from pathlib import 

target_path = Path("my_base_dir")
for p in target_path.glob("**/*"):
    if p.is_dir():
        print(p.name)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your third line.

```
import pathlib 

target_path = pathlib.Path("")
for p in target_path.glob("**/*/*"):
    if p.is_dir():
        print(p.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parts of a path with `.parts`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# 'so' is a venv for python containing a few subdirectories
paths = list(filter(lambda p: p.is_dir(), Path('so').rglob('*')))

# only subdirectories with depth 2
subdir_names = [path.parts[1] for path in paths if len(path.parts) == 2]
# ['Include', 'Lib', 'Scripts', 'share']

# all subdirectories
all_subdirs = [Path(*path.parts[1:]) for path in paths if len(path.parts) >= 2]
# [WindowsPath('Include'), WindowsPath('Lib'), WindowsPath('Scripts'), WindowsPath('share'),
#  WindowsPath('Lib/site-packages'), WindowsPath('Lib/site-packages/backcall'), ... ]

# all subdirectories alternative
all_subdirs = [path.relative_to(Path('so')) for path in paths if len(path.parts) >= 2]
# [WindowsPath('Include'), WindowsPath('Lib'), WindowsPath('Scripts'), WindowsPath('share'),
#  WindowsPath('Lib/site-packages'), WindowsPath('Lib/site-packages/backcall'), ... ]
```